# what's the easy way to create low poly background by adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, portrait

eaxamples: look at these background and portrait

[image]

Comment: To me that looks like the result of automation, not manual creation, I assume here is a plugin to do that...

Comment: Thank's for your respond, can you mention me some of these plugin.

Comment: Sorry I can't no, as I said, I ASSUME...! - I'm sure someone will be able to help soon

Comment: Google will show you the way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows little to not effort.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm sure there are tools to assist with a technique like your desired look, I was having trouble finding them. :\

But I did find some good tutorials that may give you the insight you'd like.

- Vectorboom has a fairly straight forward one - http://vectorboom.com/load/tutorials/effects/polygonal_vector_mosaic/3-1-0-305  <-- this one assumes you are using some of the supporting code - always make sure you're getting code from a source you can trust or read it for yourself and make sure it's not doing anything weird.
- There is also a rather nice one from Connecting 4 - http://connecting4.com/how-to-adobe-illustrator-geometric-art/

Answer (score -1):

I find a source explain the way to create Low poly background:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ufq0jdzhQH4

I eventually found this method, it is very easy to do, and also very fast too.